# Why do PCI devices share the same address space?

Tags: pci

When a computer starts up, the BIOS or operating system probes each PCI device to ask how much address space it wants.  Then, it allocates the appropriate space and tells each PCI device where its space begins, so the PCI device can respond to read and write requests within that range.

My question is why all the devices need to be allocated blocks from the same address space.  Why not give each device an address space of its own?

On the printed circuit board, there already is an "out-of-band" way to discriminate between PCI devices: the IDSEL line.  [This is what's used during PCI enumeration, before each device has had its space allocated.](https://superuser.com/questions/1057421/how-is-the-device-determined-in-pci-enumeration-bus-device-function)  So why not use that for post-enumeration accesses as well, and save some decoding logic on the PCI device?  Would that somehow have been slower, or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, they don't *need* to share the same address space.  Separating the device's address spaces is exactly what an IOMMU is for, and can be useful for a number of reasons:

- It can securely allow a virtual machine to directly access physical hardware with native drivers.
- It decouples the device's addressing capabilities from the physical address space.  In other words, it lets you have devices that can only do 32-bit addressing access data anywhere in physical memory, even above the first 4G.
- It lets you isolate devices from each other more thoroughly, which can significantly improve security of the system.

As far as why this isn't the default behavior, and why the IDSEL line is not used for this, I can't really say, as I don't have much knowledge of the history of PCI designs.  My first guess would be that it originally was so that it was easier to port drivers for ISA cards to PCI (ISA assumes a flat shared address space).  Also, IOMMU's are not exactly the easiest bit of hardware to design, and have only recently become widely available on x86 platforms (and are still not guaranteed, a lot of Intel chips don't have them still, and many low-end AMD chips don't either).

It may be worth pointing out though that with PCI Express, there is actually an advantage to sharing address space across devices, namely that it lets you do device-to-device transfers (though most platforms don't properly support this), which can be very useful in large grid setups that use RDMA (you can get data from remote devices directly, without needing the remote system's OS to mediate once the transfer is set up).

Answer (score 1):

For x86 systems, the CPU itself can only access two address spaces: the normal memory address space, and the IO address space.  Other systems may only have one address space (e.g. ARM, powerpc, etc.).  These two address spaces are separated from the point of view of PCI devices - different commands are used to access each address space, and bridges have separate configuration registers for each address space.  However, as the CPU can only access these two address spaces, all connected devices must be mapped in to these two address spaces.  So it's really not so much a limitation of PCI as a limitation of the architecture of the rest of the system.

I should also mention that when PCI was developed, there was no such thing as an IOMMU, that is a relatively recent addition.